# How to use the threads to create the images thumbnail

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

I'm use `QTreeView` to get the images path, then I'm use `QListView` to display the images that in specific path as thumbnail.

[image]

The problem in the period, create and display the thumbnail images.
The previous process, take a long time to done, depend on the number of images.
And for that reason I decided to use the threads, maybe helps to prevent the hung up which occur in application and increase the speed of create and display the thumbnail images.

```
void mainWidget::on_treeView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index){
    filesModel->clear();
    QFileSystemModel *sysModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(ui->treeView->model());
    QDir dir(sysModel->filePath(ui->treeView->currentIndex()));
    QFileInfoList filesList = dir.entryInfoList(QStringList() << "*.jpg" << "*.jpeg" << "*.tif" << "*.png" << "*.gif" << "*.bmp" ,QDir::Files);
    int filesCount = filesList.size();
    for(int i=0;i<filesCount;i++){
        QPixmap originalImage(filesList[i].filePath());
        if(!originalImage.isNull()){
            QPixmap scaledImage = originalImage.scaled(150, 120);    
            filesModel->setItem(i, new QStandardItem(QIcon(scaledImage), filesList[i].baseName()));
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I use threads with the previous code ?**

Comment: I'd do it just as explorer and everybody else does: show a placeholder picture and replace that when the rendering of the real one is done.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a simple and correct approach is using [`QtConcurrent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) as the following:

**Note:** If you are using Qt 5 you will need to add `QT += concurrent` to the .pro file.

Header:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void UpdateItem(int, QImage);

private slots:
    void on_treeView_clicked(const QModelIndex &);
    void List(QFileInfoList filesList, QSize size);
    void setThumbs(int index, QImage img);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFileSystemModel *model;
    QStandardItemModel *filesmodel;
    QFuture<void> thread;
    bool running;
};
```

CPP file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(1);

    model = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    model->setRootPath("\\");

    filesmodel = new QStandardItemModel(this);

    ui->treeView->setModel(model);
    ui->listView->setModel(filesmodel);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(UpdateItem(int,QImage)), SLOT(setThumbs(int,QImage)));

    ui->treeView->header()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);

    running = false;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_treeView_clicked(const QModelIndex&)
{
    filesmodel->clear();

    running = false;

    thread.waitForFinished();

    QDir dir(model->filePath(ui->treeView->currentIndex()));

    QFileInfoList filesList = dir.entryInfoList(QStringList() << "*.jpg" << "*.jpeg" << "*.tif" << "*.png" << "*.gif" << "*.bmp", QDir::Files);

    int filesCount = filesList.size();

    QPixmap placeholder = QPixmap(ui->listView->iconSize());
    placeholder.fill(Qt::gray);

    for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
        filesmodel->setItem(i, new QStandardItem(QIcon(placeholder), filesList[i].baseName()));

    running = true;

    thread = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MainWindow::List, filesList, ui->listView->iconSize());
}

void MainWindow::List(QFileInfoList filesList, QSize size)
{
    int filesCount = filesList.size();

    for (int i = 0; running && i < filesCount; i++)
    {
        QImage originalImage(filesList[i].filePath());
        if (!originalImage.isNull())
        {
            QImage scaledImage = originalImage.scaled(size);
            if (!running) return;
            emit UpdateItem(i, scaledImage);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::setThumbs(int index, QImage img)
{
    QIcon icon = QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    QStandardItem *item = filesmodel->item(index);
    filesmodel->setItem(index, new QStandardItem(icon, item->text()));
}
```

Comment: From the docs: “The QtConcurrent namespace provides high-level APIs that make it possible to write multi-threaded programs without using low-level threading primitives such as mutexes, read-write locks, wait conditions, or semaphores.” that way the `QtConcurrent` namespace is just a simplest way to multi thread, especially if you want to run just a function, not a entire class, on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use threads to keep your application responsive in this case. Use `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` in the loop to keep the application responsive. `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` will process all the events in the event queue of the thread which calls it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older thread, but still comes up in Google.  Check out the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144638/how-to-create-custom-icons-for-qfilesystemmodel-in-a-background-thread). I found the use of QIdentityProxyModel to be a bit more elegant, as it allowed QFileSystemModel to be used as the list view's model.